# Is there a way to copy character arrays of numbers which initially where inputed as string to a doubly linked list

Tags: c++

I wanted to write extremeFloat calculator that uses a doubly linked list

I have created the DLL and have accepted two number from users as string changed it to character arrays then stacked on copying this characters to the DLL.

Doubly linked list:

```
template <class T>
class DLList {
  public:
    DLList() {
    front=rare=NULL;
    }
    ~DLList();
    int isEmpty();
    int insertDigit(T data);
    node<T> *getFront() {
    return front;
    }
    int removeDigit(T data);
    void empty();
private:
    node<T> *front;
    node<T> *rare;

};
```

insertion code:

```
template <class T>
int DLList<T>::insertDigit(T data)
{

  node<T> *p;
  p = new node<T>;
  if(!p) return 0;
  p->data = data;
  p->next = p->prev = NULL;
  if(front == NULL)
    front = rare = p;
  else {

    p->prev = rare;
    rare->next = p;
    rare = p;

  }

  return 1;
}
```

main function:

```
 int main()
 {
   int n, m;
   DLList<char[]> d1;

   cout<<"Enter a number\n";
   string num = getExtreme();
   cout<<"Enter another number\n";
   string num2 = getExtreme();

   n = num.length();
   m = num2.length();

   char numChar[n+1];
   char numChar2[m+1];

   strcpy(numChar, num.c_str());
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    d1.insertDigit() = numChar[i];
   return 0;

 }
```

Unable to copy the character array to the Doubly linked list

Answer (score 1):

Firstly using an array as a template parameter is illegal. It's seems from the subsequent code that you are trying to copy individual characters to your list, so it should be a list of characters not of character arrays.

```
DLList<char> d1;
```

Now look at your `insertDigit` function. It takes a parameter and (for some reason) it returns an integer. So this syntax `d1.insertDigit() = numChar[i];` makes no sense. You've not given a parameter and you are trying to assign to the returned integer.

This is how you do it

```
d1.insertDigit(numChar[i]);
```

Another improvement, `numChar` and `numChar2` are completely unnecessary, just use `num` and `num2` directly

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
   d1.insertDigit(num[i]);
```

To me this code looks like you started with something that was nearly right but then because you didn't understand your error you tried miscellaneous changes hoping that would fix things and ended up making your code worse. It's rarely a good way to proceed, when you get an error try and understand it before making any changes. Even if you get lucky and you fix the error you won't understand why it was fixed. This leads directly to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)